# Django Confirmation Code Error (Two codes generated instead of one)

Tags: django, django-views

I am writing a class using Django that will handle getting a confirmation code from the user after they create an account.  But when the function is called, the program creates a new random code, like it should.  The issue comes in once the user enters this code and makes a post request.  A new code it generated, and this is the one that the code the user entered will be compared with.  Is there any way to get around this?

````
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class ConfirmEmail(View):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs: Any) -> None:
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.code = str(random.randint(1000, 9999))

    def get(self, request):
        email = request.GET.get('email')
        phone = request.GET.get('phone')
        send_mail(
            "Confirmation Code",
            "Your confirmation code is: " + self.code,
            "to_email",
            [email, ])
        return render(request, "views/confirm_email.html")

    def post(self, request):
        confirmation_code = request.POST.get('confirmation_code', '')
        print(confirmation_code)
        print(self.code)
        if confirmation_code == self.code:
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            # The confirmation code is incorrect, display an error message.
            return render(request, "views/confirm_email.html", {'error_message': 'Invalid confirmation code'})
```
````

Answer (score 1):

As you note. The code is being rewitten as the init function is called each time you hit the view.

A simple way to fix this would be to store the value in a session variable. Generate a new one when you recieve the GET request as the get() method has a request object argument:

```
get(self, request):
    #set the session variablef
    request.session['code'] = str(random.randint(1000, 9999))
    email = request.GET.get('email')
    phone = request.GET.get('phone')
    send_mail(
        "Confirmation Code",
        "Your confirmation code is: " + request.session.get('code')

def post(self, request):
    confirmation_code = request.POST.get('confirmation_code', '')
    print(confirmation_code)
    print(request.session.get('code'))
    #I am using request.session.get('code') rather than session['code'] to return None if empty rather than error out.
    if confirmation_code == request.session.get('code'):
        return redirect('home')
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. this works perfactly for me!

Comment: Glad it worked!  Note that this activation methoid will only work as long as the user session which may or may not suit your purposes.  A more robust method, though more complex, can be found here: https://pylessons.com/django-email-confirm